# How to detect non-virtual-override at compile or runtime

Tags: c++, crtp

I want to detect if a function was (statically) overridden in a derived class:

```
template< typename T >
struct A{ void func(){ static_cast<T*>(this)->func(); } };
struct B: A<B>{};
struct C: A<C>{ void func(){  std::cout << "class C" << std::endl;  };

C c;
if(&A<C>::func != &C::func)
  c.func();
```

Obviously, I won't call 'func' if it has no override. 
I prefer direct answers to my questions. Telling about the actual problem to determine the overloading.
I will also appreciate any answer that shows other ways to approach the general problem.

Ok, it compiles, I have yet to find the difference to my actual code, that didn't.
By the way, in my actual code, I am not just trying to avoid calling the function, there is some more. I really want to know if the function is overridden, or if I need to use a completely different method.

Comment: This sounds a lot like how SFINAE works.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense: `A` is a template, but below line 2 you use it like a non-template.

Comment: Well, this pointer comparison appears to work if you fix all the compiler errors. So?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works [here](http://ideone.com/URnTc). BTW the easiest approach would be to define `f()` in `A` as empty:

```
struct A{ void func(){ } };
```

Comment: actually, your right that it works after fixing the typos. Don't know why my actual code doesn't.
But the empty 'func' makes no sense to me. Look up CRTP on wikipedia, this is what I am going to do. Roughly.

Comment: Maybe the compiler has a bug. It doesn't work with some other versions of gcc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way to do what you're asking specifically, but you can use some cool patterns to achieve "static polymorphism" using templates.  This removes your dependency on using the v-table during runtime (really, there isn't one used to achieve the polymorphic-like effect).  So, you should be able to check at compile time if the functions you need are available.

There's a little intro about it on wikipedias template metagrogramming entry:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming

It will make your code more complex though, so i think you should just think about a redesign that doesn't require this feature - its more of a reflection attribute and C++ isn't very good at that as of yet :(